# Simplify an expression involving indices

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

One of my friends asked me this question: Simplify 
$$\frac{50^{3x-1} 10^{2-3x}}{250^{3x+1}}$$ I've been thinking about the question for more than a day. I've looked through my teacher's notes but none of the examples my teacher gave is similar to this question. It's from Form 4 syllabus, Chapter 5: Logarithms and Indices. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: "asking for a friend..."

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Two approaches:  1)If you write $250^{3x+1}=250^2\cdot 250^{3x-1}$ you can cancel some things. 2)Note that you only have factors of $2$ and $5$.  Break up $50,10,250$ into $2$'s and $5$'s  and find the exponent for each.  I think the second is what is intended, but the first is what hit me first and it may help in other situations.

Answer (score 1):

From the second hint of the first answer;
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\frac{50^{3x-1} 10^{2-3x}}{250^{3x+1}}& = \frac{5^{3x}\times2^1}{5^{3(3x+1)}\times2^{3x+1}}\\
& = 5^{-6x-3}\times 2^{-3x}\\
& =(5^{2})^{-3x}\times 2^{-3x}\times 5^{-3}\\
& =25^{-3x}\times 2^{-3x}\times 125^{-1}\\
& =\frac{50^{-3x}}{125}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}